# Export Notebook as one long pdf page using Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, export

I need to export my notebook to show my work.

I want the pdf just to look like what I see on my screen in the same format as I scroll down through my notebook.

Is it possible ?

**Edit :**

New solution, new problem, thanks to Verbeia, I was able to have obtain a "1 long page" pdf out of my notebook. But there remain weird formatting behavior as below, can we fix that ?

[image]
[image]
While my notebook looks like :

Comment: (1) Are you using MMA 8? Much improved print/export over v7. (2) Regardless, getting things to 'look like what I see on my screen' isn't easy. Start by File->Print Settings->Print Environment->Working. You'll then probably need to fiddle with the current magnification settings of the notebook--try 125% if you're on a Windows machine using 96 dpi resolution. (3) Now try the export. Also try printing to PDF---you may need to download some print-to-PDF software...search and you'll find many options. (4) It is possible to insert page breaks, although I have never used the feature. Check the docs.

Comment: @500 Sorry, you'll have to redo your thesis in Matlab ---- :)

Comment: @telefunkenv14, wow this was long to type for my four fingers ! Thank You very much I am currently trying to print a pdf with 6 feet long page. Let`s see, I have MMMA8.

Comment: @500 you only need to type the first three chars of the addressé name

Comment: @belisarius, good to know when lazy. Mathematica crashed I guess my 6 feet page is not a proper solution...

Comment: @500 http://i01.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/364290129/CAD_Plotter_Paper_for_clothing_factory.jpg

Comment: @500 Why not include an example of code that produces, in your view, an unacceptable PDF rendering when exported?

Comment: @500 That helps visualize it.  I'm still trying to imagine what you'd want to do with a 6 ft long printout. Are you sure you don't want to segment 1 into Fixation 1, Fixation 2, etc. so they are side-to-side? I'm imagining a poster-like exhibit.

Comment: @David, Basically what I want is dor somebody to explore my notebook without Mathematica, experiencing it the same way I do  :-)

Comment: @500: In which case, why not use the cdf format?

Comment: I looked once at web mathematica manual and got really scared. I would love to use CDF, but my deadline was 10 days ago :-)

Comment: @500: CDF does not require webMathematica. Just `Save As > CDF` and you have a document readable by the CDF Player. It's like saving as a pdf, but you can expand and collapse sections etc...

Comment: @Simon, Finally got it. Nasser initial illustration got me confuse. Will definitely instal that player on my committee`s computers this week  !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me under Mac OS X 10.6, Mma 8.0.1:

1. Select the whole notebook. This is easiest done if you have a top-level title or heading at the beginning of the document.
2. Choose "Save Selection As..." from the File menu (screenshot 1).
3. Choose PDF from the resulting dialog (screenshot 2).

You need to use "Save Selection As...", because "Save As" does try to calculate page breaks. If I understand your question correctly, you want a long "scroll" PDF with no page breaks. "Save Selection As..." does that.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT in response to 500's question edit**

To ensure the content goes "full width", you need to set the Printing Environment properly. I found setting the Printing Environment to the default `Printing` (see screenshot) and setting landscape paper in the Page Setup gave good results. Alternatively, you could go to the [Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) and set the Page Size or Paper Size settings for that notebook explicitly. 
(on Mac OS X you get there from the Mathematica menu > Preferences > Advanced Tab > Show Option Inspector button > Notebook options > Printing options > Printing Options)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, best solution so far for me. Still distortion happening but easier to control now with the page.

Comment: Verbeia, please let me know if you can do anything on my Edit. many thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Verbeia hi, Is it possible to implement such settings by Mathematica's built-in function, e.g., Export[]?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether this will help for the this specific case. You can explicitly enter a page break into Mathematica using Insert > Page Break (appears at the bottom of the Insert menu). Try doing that before and after the image you have here.

Exporting by saving the notebook as a pdf and exporting by using the Export function often have different results as well. You may wish to try using the Export function out.